# What are those green LED arrays on top of the instrument panel called?

Tags: flight-instruments, firefighting

Below is the link showing a fire fighting aircraft

From 0:23 to 0:45 an LED array can be seen. The peculiar thing about that is as aircraft approaches the site, all the LEDs are glowing, and vice versa when the aircraft leaves the site.

Comment: The lights are for the tanker drop system. The individual lights indicate tank door status. Green means armed and ready to drop. This video shows the same type of aircraft doing a partial load drop with 4 tanks remaining full after the drop. https://youtu.be/oSC5PriYrI4

Comment: The aircraft is an Avro RJ. I don’t see all the lights “glowing” as they depart. When they drop at 0:37 you can see all the lights flashing and then only they go out with a single green flashing on the right. (probably one door closing a little slow). As they climb away you see one solid green visible on the left side which is probably the system master light.

Comment: Thank you Gentleman.